# Error while is docker pull image

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have taken `docker login` and : `docker pull xxx/image_name` , but I got eror:

```
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository xxx/image_name: "\"The Repository is Locked, access denied\
```

I have searched on google but no luck,

Please give me some suggestions, thanks in advance !

Comment: it's named is : test_4005

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/pull-error-the-repository-is-locked-access-denied/2178/3

Comment: https://success.docker.com/Cloud/Solve/Pull_error_%E2%80%9DThe_Repository_is_Locked,_access_denied%22

Comment: thanks, it resolve !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may occur for two reasons, as described [in this link](https://forums.docker.com/t/pull-error-the-repository-is-locked-access-denied/2178/8):

User has their Default Repository Visibility set to Private and they push a new repository using the Docker CLI. If you don't have any free private repositories available, then the new repository will become locked due to the visibility defaulting as Private.

Decline in payment collection for the current subscription plan for the private repositories.

If you encounter such a problem, please change your default repository visibility to Public and push your image to a public repository.  If you need the repository to remain private, confirm you have enough private repositories available and that your billing is current.  If neither of these methods are relevant to your issue please send an email to billing@docker.com.