# Docker run Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository Unable to access the repository:

Tags: docker

I am getting error running a docker container using the following command.

$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t gcr.io//hello-dotnet:v1

```
vinay@dotnet-project-146402:~/HelloWorld$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet:v1
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet:v1' locally
Pulling repository gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet: "Unable to access the repository: dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet; please verify that it exists and you have permission to access it (no valid credential w
as supplied)."
```

----------------------Update----------------

```
vinay@dotnet-project-146402:~/HelloWorld$ docker pull gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet:v1
Pulling repository gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet: "Unable to access the repository: dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet; please verify that it exists and you have permission to access it (no valid credential w
as supplied)."
```

----------------------Update----------------

```
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/vinay/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
vinay@dotnet-project-146402:~/HelloWorld$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet:v1
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet:v1' locally
Pulling repository gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet: "Unable to access the repository: dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet; please verify that it exists and you have permission to access it."
vinay@dotnet-project-146402:~/HelloWorld$ docker pull gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet:v1
Pulling repository gcr.io/dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet: "Unable to access the repository: dotnet-project-146402/hello-dotnet; please verify that it exists and you have permission to access it."
vinay@dotnet-project-146402:~/HelloWorld$
```

The docker login command is

```
docker login -e vinay@vinayjoseph.com -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io
```

Comment: Can you do `docker pull gcr.io//hello-dotnet:v1` and see what it says?

Comment: see update in the question

Comment: Updated again. Please see question.

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment, behind a proxy?

Comment: google cloud shell

Comment: Did you take a look at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524811/error-while-is-docker-pull-image

Comment: Are your credentials valid? `docker login gcr.io`

Comment: I have never done logged in. Sorry new to docker.

Comment: You need to go through this https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication once you login you should be all set

Comment: I am still getting the same error after loggin in.

Comment: see comments in the latest update to the question

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926813/pull-private-docker-images-from-google-container-registry-w-o-gcloud

Comment: Show us the `docker login` command you are using. Looks like you can log in to gcr.io but still the user you are using doesn't have access to your repository